# Having trouble determining a 2D feature matrix structure to feed into machine learning algorithm

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning, computer-vision, scikit-learn

I am training an emotion recognition system that detects emotions through facial movement as a result, I have formed a 4 dimensional matrix that I am trying to reduce to 2 dimensions.

**Features that makes up the 4D matrix:**
Number of videos (and each video will be assigned emotion label)
Number of frames per video
Direction of the facial landmarks per frame
Speed of the facial landmarks per frame

**The important features that I am trying to train with:**
The left side is the speed (hypotenuse between same facial landmark each frame)
The right side is direction (arctan of the x and y values of the same facial landmark each frame)

**The 4D matrix that I am stuck with and trying to reduce to 2D**

```
>> main.shape  
(60, 17, 68, 2)  
# 60 videos, 17 frames per video, 68 facial landmarks, 2 features (direction and speed)  
>> main  
array([[[[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [  1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         ..., 
         [  3.        ,   1.        ],
         [  3.        ,   1.        ],
         [  3.        ,   1.        ]],

        [[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         ..., 
         [  2.        ,   1.        ],
         [  3.        ,   1.        ],
         [  3.        ,   1.        ]],

        ..., 
        [[  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         [  1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         ..., 
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816]],

        [[  2.23606798,  -0.46364761],
         [  2.82842712,  -0.78539816],
         [  2.23606798,  -0.46364761],
         ..., 
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ]],

        [[ -1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         [ -2.23606798,  -0.46364761],
         [ -2.23606798,  -0.46364761],
         ..., 
         [  1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         [  1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         [  2.23606798,  -1.10714872]]],


       [[[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[  2.        ,   1.        ],
         [  2.23606798,  -1.10714872],
         [  1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         ..., 
         [ -2.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -1.41421356,  -0.78539816]],

        [[  2.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -2.23606798,   1.10714872],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         ..., 
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ]],

        ..., 
        [[ -2.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -3.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -4.12310563,  -0.24497866],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -2.23606798,   1.10714872]],

        [[ -2.23606798,   1.10714872],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [ -2.23606798,   1.10714872],
         ..., 
         [ -2.23606798,   0.46364761],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816]],

        [[  2.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [  2.82842712,   0.78539816],
         ..., 
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -2.23606798,  -1.10714872]]],


       [[[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [ -3.        ,  -0.        ],
         [ -2.        ,  -0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        ..., 
        [[  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  2.        ,   1.        ],
         [  3.        ,   1.        ],
         [  3.        ,   1.        ]],

        [[ -7.28010989,   1.29249667],
         [ -7.28010989,   1.29249667],
         [ -8.54400375,   1.21202566],
         ..., 
         [-22.02271555,   1.52537305],
         [ 22.09072203,  -1.48013644],
         [ 22.36067977,  -1.39094283]],

        [[  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [ -1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.41421356,   0.78539816]]],


       ..., 
       [[[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[  5.38516481,   0.38050638],
         [  5.09901951,   0.19739556],
         [  4.47213595,  -0.46364761],
         ..., 
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [ -2.82842712,   0.78539816],
         [ -5.        ,   0.64350111]],

        [[ -6.32455532,   0.32175055],
         [ -6.08276253,  -0.16514868],
         [ -5.65685425,  -0.78539816],
         ..., 
         [  3.60555128,   0.98279372],
         [  5.        ,   0.92729522],
         [  5.65685425,   0.78539816]],

        ..., 
        [[ -3.16227766,  -0.32175055],
         [ -3.60555128,  -0.98279372],
         [  5.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [ 12.08304597,   1.14416883],
         [ 13.15294644,   1.418147  ],
         [ 14.31782106,   1.35970299]],

        [[  3.60555128,  -0.5880026 ],
         [  4.47213595,  -1.10714872],
         [  6.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [-20.39607805,   1.37340077],
         [-21.02379604,   1.52321322],
         [-22.09072203,   1.48013644]],

        [[  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [  4.12310563,   1.32581766],
         [  4.        ,   1.        ],
         [  4.12310563,   1.32581766]]],


       [[[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -2.23606798,   1.10714872],
         ..., 
         [ -3.16227766,   0.32175055],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.41421356,  -0.78539816]],

        [[  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [  3.        ,   1.        ],
         [  2.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816]],

        ..., 
        [[  5.38516481,  -1.19028995],
         [  4.47213595,  -1.10714872],
         [  4.12310563,  -1.32581766],
         ..., 
         [  2.23606798,  -0.46364761],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -1.        ,  -0.        ]],

        [[ -5.38516481,   1.19028995],
         [ -4.12310563,   1.32581766],
         [ -3.16227766,   1.24904577],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.41421356,  -0.78539816]],

        [[  8.06225775,   1.44644133],
         [ -7.07106781,  -1.42889927],
         [  6.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [ -3.16227766,  -0.32175055],
         [ -3.16227766,  -0.32175055],
         [ -3.16227766,  -0.32175055]]],


       [[[  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ]],

        [[ -2.23606798,   0.46364761],
         [ -1.41421356,   0.78539816],
         [ -2.23606798,   0.46364761],
         ..., 
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ]],

        [[ -2.23606798,  -0.46364761],
         [ -1.41421356,  -0.78539816],
         [  2.        ,   1.        ],
         ..., 
         [  0.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   0.        ]],

        ..., 
        [[  1.        ,   0.        ],
         [  1.        ,   1.        ],
         [ -2.23606798,  -1.10714872],
         ..., 
         [ 19.02629759,   1.51821327],
         [ 19.        ,   1.        ],
         [-19.10497317,  -1.46591939]],

        [[  3.60555128,   0.98279372],
         [  3.60555128,   0.5880026 ],
         [  5.        ,   0.64350111],
         ..., 
         [  7.28010989,  -1.29249667],
         [  7.61577311,  -1.16590454],
         [  8.06225775,  -1.05165021]],

        [[ -7.28010989,   1.29249667],
         [ -5.        ,   0.92729522],
         [ -5.83095189,   0.5404195 ],
         ..., 
         [ 20.09975124,   1.47112767],
         [ 21.02379604,   1.52321322],
         [-20.22374842,  -1.42190638]]]])
```

The direction and speed features are quite valuable (the most important features) as it represents the movement of each facial landmark per frame and I am trying to get the machine learning algorithm to train base on that

I tried to reshape three of the dimensions into one long vector (just mushed speed, direction, and frame all together) and finally formed a 2D matrix, I fed it into sklearn SVM function and it produced a rather low accuracy. I expected this as I figured there is no way the ml algorithm would recognize that the difference between the features in the giant single matrix and assume that everything in the vector is the same features.

**The 2D matrix I was forced to make to feed in sklearn SVM by forcing speed, direction, and video per frame all into one vector, and got a low accuracy with:**

```
>> main
array([[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,  -0.78539816,
          2.23606798,  -1.10714872],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,   1.        ,
         -2.23606798,  -1.10714872],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,   1.        ,
          1.41421356,   0.78539816],
       ..., 
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,   1.        ,
          4.12310563,   1.32581766],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,  -0.32175055,
         -3.16227766,  -0.32175055],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,   1.52321322,
        -20.22374842,  -1.42190638]])
>> main.shape
(60, 2312)
```

I want to preserve the speed and direction features, but have to represent them in a 2D matrix that takes into account the frames in the video.

The emotion label will be attached to each of the 17 frames in each video. (so basically, the 17 frame video will be labeled as an emotion)

**Is there any smart way in reshaping and reducing the 4D matrix that would accomplish this?**

Comment: You are using scikit-learn and `numpy`.  This is **not** a MATLAB question.   You are using Python.  As such, I've retagged your post to reflect this.  Please avoid using the MATLAB tag when your question does not deal with the MATLAB environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the way that you've framed the question you will absolutely see poor accuracy and there's very little you can do to change it. Assigning a single emotion to a video (depending on your corpus), is generally inaccurate enough that any machine learning algorithm will have trouble learning the signal you're trying to pull out.

Additionally, you've framed the problem as a time-series problem, which is going to make your life a headache, especially if you're using off-the-shelf `sklearn` algorithms, which are very poorly suited for this kind of task.

If at all possible, you should instead frame your problem as a `computer vision` problem. You should attempt to predict on each individual frame, what the emotion content is. If you don't have a dataset with that level of granularity, you just aren't going to see great accuracy.

It's a little bit of a departure from the way in which you asked the question, but the way in which you've asked the question it's non-tractable. Here is, instead, the way that you should approach the problem:

- Label individual frames with emotional content
- Train an image-based algorithm to categorize those tagged frames

  - Convolutional neural networks will likely give you the best performance for any image-based problem where you have a decently-sized dataset
  - If that is not an option, you need to develop a 1d feature representation of the image. I would personally suggest using [indico's](http://indico.io/docs?python) image features API. Once you have this representation a typical algorithm like an SVM will work great.
- If accuracy is not quite to your liking, but is getting close I would recommend using a pre-processing/data-augmentation pipeline like the one details [here.](http://benanne.github.io/2015/03/17/plankton.html) Granted, that example is for plankton identification, the basic approach is identical
- If the accuracy still isn't up to snuff, and you need to predict on the entire video you will then want to aggregate your results to give accurate results over the entire video

  - One method is to train a convolutional neural network on a graph of the predictions you've made over the video. This is kind of weird, but might work pretty well
  - A good approach would be to use a bayesian method, assuming each prediction has a certain level of confidence, and combining the prediction distributions over the video.
  - The best approach is to treat this as an ensemble learning problem. Luckily, ensemble learning is a very well-studied and understood problem. You can find details of how to combine multiple predictions in this format [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning)

I hope this has been helpful! Let me know if you have any more questions.

Disclaimer: I am the CEO of indico, so I may be biased in recommending its use.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will rethink my approach to this problem and try your method. For features, do you still think I still keep my speed and direction features as I attach an emotion label to each frame to indicate the frame's previous movement, or do you recommend that I scrape those and make completely new set of features?

Comment: So, it's possible that adding the speed and direction features will help improve accuracy, but if I had to guess the improvement will be marginal.

Comment: I am probably going to go with the neural network method.  I would like to take advantage of the fact that I can use facial landmarks and want to create an emotion recognition system based on facial movement. What kind of features would you recommend to optimize my accuracy?

Comment: That depends, @user3377126, how many labelled examples do you have?

Comment: Since I was labeling each video with an emotion, I have around 500-600 videos labeled with emotions (I recorded them myself), each with 17 frames. In each frame, there are 68 facial landmarks that labels eyes, eyebrows, mouth, nose, and borders of the face.

Comment: Hmm, that's a little bit of an issue. The problem is that 8500 examples isn't a huge dataset, so a traditional deep learning approach probably won't work that well. If you want to keep trying a neural net approach I would advise using a net pre-trained on a dataset like [this](https://www.kaggle.com/c/challenges-in-representation-learning-facial-expression-recognition-challenge). Combining the features learned at the highest level from that pre-trained CNN with a direct input of your keypoint motion features will probably yield the best results.